# Jenkins Jacoco Coverage Plugin removes previously generated coverage data if build fails

Tags: jenkins, jacoco

The problem is so simple, but I have not found a solution yet! I use Jacoco Coverage Plugin in Jenkins. Whenever a build fails, all previous coverage data are gone! I want to know how to avoid that. Is it a bug or something that I'm not aware of?

For example for one fail build, I got this in the console:

```
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /root/.jenkins/workspace/Project/HTMLReport to /root/.jenkins/jobs/Project/builds/118/htmlreports/HTML_Report
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It depends whether you failed before you even reached Jenkins's post build step for publishing, Jacoco code coverage data. If you failed before and your build process is cleaning up the folders/files which Jacoco Coverage plugin is looking at the show the reports, you won't see anything on the job's dashboard. But if the build failed after it's done with the compile/jacoco instrumentation and you somehow (ignore failures is true) ran the post step, then you'll see the reports. Also, see if Archiving the .exec files and the source (src/java etc ), report folders help or not.

Comment: @ArunSangal, I edited the question, please review it! It seems Jacoco Coverage has not been called. BTW, please tell me what you exactly mean about `ignore failures is true` and please also explain me how could I archive `.exec` and source files. Is there any settings to archive it automatically? Just like HTML Report which has a `Keep past HTML reports` check-box.

Comment: ignoreFaiures=true is one setting in Gradle build system where im telling my build/test running task/target that im telling the build system (Gradle/ANT/Maven etc) not to fail if something fails i.e. it'll let Jenkins to proceed and do what's next in the job's configurations. Archive artifacts is one option that you can select in Jenkins job (See Post build action). You should also look into using SonarQube where you can publish data per build run i.e. if one build fails, it'll still retain the last build/ or previous build's history/data. Seems like you are aleady doing some archiving.

Comment: That's true, if build failed before Jacoco even got a chance to do anything, Jacoco report on the job's dashboard won't show up as I mentioned earlier, that report looks into the job's workspace "http://yourjenkinsserver:xxxx/job/jobName/ws/.../...". and if that's doesn't have data due to a failed build cleaning some folders under the workspace then you can do anything. What you should is: Archive artifacts (as post build action) and put archive all the folder/files which Jacoco needs (exec, html, etc) per build and then at least you can see the jacoco report for a given #NN build that way.